Deserialize Steam's libraryfolders.vdf into an object (C#)
Hi guys just like i mentioned in the title
how can i achieve this im using (C# winforms app)
This is the class suggested by chatgpt
 public class LibraryFolder
 {
     [JsonProperty("path")]
     public string Path { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("label")]
     public string Label { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("contentid")]
     public string ContentId { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("totalsize")]
     public string TotalSize { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("update_clean_bytes_tally")]
     public string UpdateCleanBytesTally { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("time_last_update_corruption")]
     public string TimeLastUpdateCorruption { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("apps")]
     public Dictionary<string, string> Apps { get; set; }
 }

 public class LibraryFolders
 {
     [JsonProperty("libraryfolders")]
     public Dictionary<string, LibraryFolder> Folders { get; set; }
 }

the vdf file structure
"libraryfolders"
{
    "0"
    {
        "path"      "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam"
        "label"     ""
        "contentid"     "5550620392854745497"
        "totalsize"     "0"
        "update_clean_bytes_tally"      "238642392488"
        "time_last_update_corruption"       "0"
        "apps"
        {
            "228980"        "357480531"
            "945360"        "689376424"
            "985890"        "6548041619"
            "1517290"       "95128078188"
            "1778820"       "100500524846"
            "1938090"       "184405249709"
        }
    }
    "1"
    {
        "path"      "D:\\SteamLibrary"
        "label"     ""
        "contentid"     "1453810943595427981"
        "totalsize"     "2000396742656"
        "update_clean_bytes_tally"      "93906442653"
        "time_last_update_corruption"       "1699831300"
        "apps"
        {
            "245490"        "11432082707"
            "311210"        "133896099794"
            "359550"        "58545464328"
            "393080"        "22467438334"
            "393100"        "65369853349"
            "1145350"       "4410444248"
            "1145360"       "11899644249"
            "1283190"       "4265400020"
            "1426210"       "48085653354"
            "1492070"       "21343562585"
            "2379390"       "68970137179"
        }
    }
    "2"
    {
        "path"      "E:\\Steam Games"
        "label"     ""
        "contentid"     "6127372622968160148"
        "totalsize"     "2000397791232"
        "update_clean_bytes_tally"      "0"
        "time_last_update_corruption"       "0"
        "apps"
        {
        }
    }
}

can someone help ? all i want is just to display the id or the key (the number on top of each library folder and the Path) in a datagrideview and also want to add or delete expect the first(default steam folder)
i used newtonsoft json and gameloop.vdf but no luck ,lots of errors , and i know i am a newbie help please thanks

I have provided an answer but in future make sure add you working to the question accordingly

thanx for the answer @Selaka , next time i will , there is a problem in the oadLibraryFolders method
libraryFolders.Folders is null cant loop to read values

Handle the null via debugging. Appreciate marking it the correct answer or giving an upvote :-) TIA

*LoadLibraryFolders

Since you already have your class file. You can load contents via System.IO.File.ReadAllText operation and do the add | delete operation accordingly.
Refer the code below:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Gameloop.Vdf;
using Gameloop.Vdf.JsonConverter;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private LibraryFolders libraryFolders;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadLibraryFolders();
        BindDataToDataGridView();
    }

    private void LoadLibraryFolders()
    {
        var vdfContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("path_to_your_vdf_file.vdf"); // load the vdf file | pass your file path here.
        var vdfData = VdfConvert.Deserialize(vdfContent);
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vdfData.Value);
        libraryFolders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LibraryFolders>(json);
    }

    private void BindDataToDataGridView()
    {
        var bindingList = new BindingList<LibraryFolderDisplay>();

        foreach (var kvp in libraryFolders.Folders)
        {
            bindingList.Add(new LibraryFolderDisplay { Id = kvp.Key, Path = kvp.Value.Path });
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingList;
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Generate a new id
        var newId = (libraryFolders.Folders.Count).ToString();
        var newFolder = new LibraryFolder { Path = "New Path", Label = "", ContentId = "0", TotalSize = "0", UpdateCleanBytesTally = "0", TimeLastUpdateCorruption = "0", Apps = new Dictionary<string, string>() };
        libraryFolders.Folders.Add(newId, newFolder);
        BindDataToDataGridView();
    }

    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            var selectedRow = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
            var idToDelete = selectedRow.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString();

            if (idToDelete != "0") // disable deleting the default folder
            {
                libraryFolders.Folders.Remove(idToDelete);
                BindDataToDataGridView();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Default library folder cannot be deleted.");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class LibraryFolderDisplay // helper class move accordinly to another folder if you wish
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}

PS:
Do make sure to install nuget packages:
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
Install-Package Gameloop.Vdf

